# Linq запрос + left

Tags: linq2sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

Всем привет! Ребят есть табличка записей, вот такой линк запрос, стала задача добавить табличку SEO, обе таблички соединяются по айдишникам (Record.id = SEO.record_id). Все бы хорошо, но не на каждую запись в табличке SEO есть строка (не все записи SEO оптимизированы), поэтому данный запрос выдает только те записи, айдишки которых есть в табл SEO. В простом SQL решается left... а как в линке? Гуглил, но синтаксис непонятный, тем более с моим вариантом. Подскажите пж как тут выкрутиться

```
var list = (from rec in db.Records
            join usr in db.UserProfiles on rec.User_id equals usr.id
            join cat in db.CategoriesRecord on rec.Category equals cat.id
            join seo in db.SEOs on rec.id equals seo.id_record

            where rec.Type == 3 && rec.is_publish == true && rec.DateTimePublish < DateTime.Now && rec.Deleted == false
            orderby rec.DateTimePublish descending

            select new { record = rec, user = usr, pathToCat = cat.PathToImg, seo = seo }).Take(NumberRecords).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не напутал, будет так:

```
var list = (from rec in db.Records
                join usr in db.UserProfiles on rec.User_id equals usr.id
                join cat in db.CategoriesRecord on rec.Category equals cat.id
                join seo in db.SEOs on rec.id equals seo.id_record 
                                             //нужна группировка в коллекцию
                                                               into seos
            //которая используется далее
             from s in seos.DefaultIfEmpty()//если коллекция пуста - пустое значение

            where rec.Type == 3 && rec.is_publish == true && rec.DateTimePublish < DateTime.Now && rec.Deleted == false
            orderby rec.DateTimePublish descending

            select new {
                      record = rec,
                      user = usr,
                      pathToCat = cat.PathToImg,
                      seo = s //заменено
                      }).Take(NumberRecords).AsEnumerable();
```

Вся соль в том, что как такового левого объединения нет. Вместо этого каждой записи ставится в соответствие коллекция записей сео, из которой далее производится выборка.